# fade two or more divs one by one after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I want to fade out the first div and fade in the next div.

If I click in the second div a button the second div should fade out and the third div should fade in.

I try this JS:

```
    $(function () {
        var fragen_gesamt = $('.dmd-container-frage').length;
        $('.dmd-container-frage').hide();
        $('.dmd-container-frage:first-child').show();
        $('.btn').on('click', function () {
            $('.dmd-container-frage:first-child').fadeOut(500, function () {
                $(this).next('.dmd-container-frage').fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
    });
```

But it's fading only to the second div.

https://jsfiddle.net/neo3d0m2/

Comment: may be problem in class .dmd-container-frage:first-child because u always call next() from first-child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change selector in you click function. Now you finding first block, and fadein next (which is second), what you need is to find parent of clicked button and do rest of logic according to this element:

```
    $(function() {
      var fragen_gesamt = $('.dmd-container-frage').length;
      $('.dmd-container-frage').hide();
      $('.dmd-container-frage:first-child').show();
      $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.dmd-container-frage').fadeOut(500, function() {
          var $el = $(this).next('.dmd-container-frage');
          // Check if there is next element
          if ($el.length) {
            $(this).next('.dmd-container-frage').fadeIn(1000);
          } else {
            alert('done!')
          }

        });
      });

    });
```

Check out this fiddle - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74n9qm77/1/)

Comment: Thats great. Can you tell me how I can provide to show a alert message if the last div was clicked? My intention is - after clicking the last div the user should redirect to another page.